# Why are the bridges of Klingon ships so steamy?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

> Apart from looking **evil**, is there any particular reason as to why these rooms look like saunas?
>
> [image]

(from [Arik Beremzon](http://www.quora.com/Arik-Beremzon) via [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Trek-movie-TV-and-creative-franchise/Why-are-the-bridges-of-Klingon-ships-so-steamy?share=1))

Comment: Because it looks cool.

Comment: That's not condensed steam but smoke from the (Neanderthal-like) cave fires.  (To me, ST:NG seemed very species-ist relative to the original series, which was from a "less enlightened" time.)

Comment: I would assume for the same reason that klingon ships look "dirty". Klingon's don't value visually appealing ships as  more important as more practical reasons, like hardware functioning (e.g. shields, weapons etc.).

Comment: Maybe its just how they like their atmosphere? Or it's a chemical that helps them live in space somehow?

Comment: I thought it was steamy because they prefer warm (and perhaps tropical?) environments, since Be'lanna almost froze in an icy environment in one Voyager episode.

Comment: Maybe the Klingon women kept it so steamy.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The production notes for the Klingon warships designed for the original TOS series Klingons stated:

- The goal of the Klingon warship was battle, not comfort. They did not have exploration ships like the Federation, all of their ships were created for war. Food was barely edible, crews were always training, a lust for combat was always promoted. Honor and glory were the Klingon meat and drink.
- Klingon ships were designed by the production teams to appear crowded, tight and cramped reinforcing a ship which was a highly utilitarian environment. They were meant to evoke the idea of a ship that has been out on patrol too long.
- The interior of Klingon vessels was designed mimic an old World War II submarine complete with a darkened interior, red lighting, smoky, poorly filtered environments and a crew hardened by these conditions, ready, willing and spoiling for a fight.

[image]

*Working the submarine motif, complete with periscope.*

The goal of seeing an interior of a Klingon ship was to show you the belly of the beast, a fearsome, barely contained crew which lives in deprivation in order to be ready to maximize the glory from boarding your ship and decorating their bat'leths with your entrails.

Qapla'! (A Klingon salute for success in battle.)

Comment: no wonder they always think it's a good day to die, you'd not want to live in those conditions :)

Comment: What kind of submarine has vaulted ceilings on the bridge (or steps for that matter)?  The examples look substantially less cramped than the images presented on television of submarines.  (They appear to be more comparably spacious to *passenger* sections of some private jets.)  Perhaps the Klingons are merely *less* decadent than contemporary humans.

Comment: The comparison is made when you find out how little of the starships are made with amenities. The literature indicates some Klingon ships were made with stasis chambers so they didn't have to feed crew on long missions. Yes, the ceilings may appear vaulted but the percentage of the ship that is set aside for comfort is proportionately very small.

Comment: So Klingon ships ran on diesel. Who knew?

Comment: ooc: you need relatively high ceilings in a movie set to enable the cameras space to move and for the lights as well. Design of the ships follows from that.

Comment: "production notes for the Klingon warships designed for the original TOS series" - could you clarify the souce or context for this, please? Unless I'm mistaken, we didn't see the interior of a single Klingon vessel during the entire run of TOS; this started only in the movies. This weakly corresponds with the mentioned focus on "honor", which was a trait added to the Klingons only after TOS (although it is a somewhat flexible term and the authors *might* have referred to a different interpretation of "honor" than the one that is frequently made explicit later on).